# ruby - strange param behavior

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I accidentally created following check, that works fine, but I'm curious why :)

1. First of all, I know I can assign `:a` instead of 'a' ;)
2. I know the right formula for this check, I'm just curious why this works
3. I don't care about optimizing this (read 2)

```
if params['a'] < 0 || params['a'] > params['b || params[:b] < 1]
```

Why this works, if there is no closing after `['b`.

Apart from this everything works fine, until I remove last `]`, or change it to something else.

UPDATE:

Here is output from ruby:

```
irb> params

 => {"a"=>3, "id2"=>"2", "b"=>2, "id"=>"1", :id=>"2"}

irb> if params['a'] < 0 || params['a'] > params['b' || params[:b] < 1]
irb>   puts 'strange...'
irb> end

strange...

=> nil
```

Comment: Have you tried to write a simple ruby file containing the line above?

Comment: Err, that code definitely doesn't work. Are you positive that's what you have? Perhaps you have a `'` later that it's matching?

Comment: you're right, something went wrong while pasting, here is originall code that I use ( ' was missing after 'b):

if params['a'] < 0 || params['a'] > params['b' || params[:b] < 1]

Comment: @adiel-mittmann
Yes I did try:

`params

> => {"a"=>3, "id2"=>"2", "b"=>2, "id"=>"1", :id=>"2"}

> if params['a'] < 0 || params['a'] > params['b' || params[:b] < 1]

>    puts 'strange...'

>  end

> strange...

>  => nil`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it certainly looks like you have an open quote which gets closed somewhere else, later down the road, on some other line.

Fun fact:

```
ruby_hash = {}
ruby_hash['class Atom
def initialize
end
end'] = 0
```

Works. Because it's just a string key. So you're just evaluating a huge long string as a key to to the 'params' hash which is most certainly going to evaluate to *nil* because it's not an existing key in the hash.

---

Edit!
You edited the question and gave more information. Let's break this down.

```
params = {"a"=>3, "id2"=>"2", "b"=>2, "id"=>"1", :id=>"2"}
# Simple enough, nothing strange here.
if params['a'] < 0 || params['a'] > params['b' || params[:b] < 1]
    puts 'strange...'
end
The plot thickens, or does it?
```

If!

```
params['a'] < 0
```

That means, of course: if the value of " a " in params is less than 0

```
||
```

... That means 'or'

```
params['a'] >
```

Stopping here for a sec - if the value of 'a' is greater than....

```
params['b' || params[:b] < 1]
```

Wait, what? Let's look deeper.

```
params[ => We look inside the hash
'b' || params[:b] < 1 ## HERE IS THE 'MAGIC' => 'b' || params[:b] < 1
] # end of the key
```

So the magic is :
We want the result of the OR statement between :

- the string 'b'
- the evaluation of 'params[:b] < 1

So what is really happening? Well, in truth, since 'b' is not false, it will just return the value of params['b'], so this is what your if statement really is:

```
if params['a'] < 0 || params['a'] > params['b']
```

If 'b' evaluated to false for whatever reason, you would end up with "params[params[b:] < 1]" which in your case would be false and would then means "params[false].

Does this make sense?

Comment: exactly it ends at the end of the whole line, I have pasted that too.
and I'm sorry there is a typo, now I will paste the whole line again as it didn't paste properly. there is  ' closing the 'b:


`if params['a'] < 0 || params['a'] > params['b' || params[:b] < 1]`

so why this works?

Comment: Edited my answer to give deeper explanation.